# How to refresh the datagrid values based on the addition or updation or deletion between two user controls?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, eventaggregator

There are two user controls
1. First User control, having only Datagrid views only
2. Second User control, having the Details & operations like addition, modification & deletion button.
Both the user control will be placed in the Main window.

Whenever i am selecting a row in the grid particular data is displayed in the second user control (Using PRISM eventAggregator). But when adding or updating or deleting it is not happening updating the first user control data grid.  How to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good point to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) it represents a dynamic data collection that gives a notification when items get added or removed.

If you are already using this which is not clear from your question, then you should check if you are using the INotifyChanged correctly or give us some code so we can help you.

But with the ObservableCollection and the INotifyChanged you should be able to solve your own question.

Comment: Thanks. As per your logic i have implemented the observablecollection it is working fine i.e. whenever i am new record  the added one is displaying in the other user control.

Comment: But when i am selecting a row from the datagrid the selection is not happening.

Comment: I have uploaded the code in the github link is   https://github.com/vishnuvarthandkv/ClarificationWPF.git    it is in public mode only so you can refer to it.